# How do I make my while loop fire once a minute?

Tags: groovy, smartthings

I have this while loop:

```
while (now() > timeToday(checkTime).time && now() < timeToday(arrivalTime).time){
```

I would like for this loop to run only when the real time clock's seconds hits `00` Basically allowing the loop to run once per minute. I am doing this because the IDE I am writing in only allows a 15 second pause maximum. Unfortunately `sleep()` is not an option at all in the SmartThings IDE

I was thinking something like this

```
while (now() > timeToday(checkTime).time && 
       now() < timeToday(arrivalTime).time && 
       Date.parse('ss', now() = 00).time){
```

But I'm fumbling with it.

If there is a better way to do this than the conditional please let me know.

Comment: Any reason `Thread.sleep` (or Groovy's default static `sleep`) won't work?

Comment: It's worth noting is running on the SmartThings platform not vanilla groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmartThings finally gave an answer back and said to use their `runIn(60, myHandler)` logic.

Thanks for everyones input.

Answer (score 2):

For scenarios like "once a minute" , You may take a look at [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long)) which can be easily used in groovy way.

```
new Timer().schedule({
    // your logic here
} as TimerTask, startTime, 1000)
```

I would recommend reading the javadoc thoroughly to understand the scheduling contract (correctness of tick).

Answer (score 1):

You could try `sleep 60*1000` to sleep for a minute in a loop before iterating over next cycle

```
while true
{
  sleep 60*1000
  //do your stuff here
  //make sure to include break logic to exit out of the loop
}
```

Comment: the IDE wont allow `sleep()` either :(

Comment: `java.lang.SecurityException: Invoking class script14057093772401260321749.sleep() is not allowed @ line 140`